# C# how to initialize generic int array with nulls instead of zeros?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

If I declare the following:

```
    public T[] GetFoo<T>(int length)
    {
        return new T[length];
    }
```

and in client code I call the above like this:

```
int[] foo = GetFoo<int>(3);
```

Then `foo[]` will be initialized like this:

```
foo[0]=0;
foo[1]=0;
foo[2]=0;
```

Is there a way that I can have it initialized like this instead?

```
foo[0]=null;
foo[1]=null;
foo[2]=null;
```

I ask because '0' has special meaning and I would like to use 'null' instead to indicate that the array element has not been set. Notice that I am using generics, and sometimes I won't be working with int's - for example sometimes I might be working with reference types.

Comment: `int` can't hold null, if you want to store null then use `Nullable<int>` or `int?` or some reference type.

Comment: ints ***can't*** be null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` is a value type which cannot be set to `null`.  If you want to allow for nulls, you must use [`Nullable<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) as your type parameter, or more succintly `int?`.

```
int?[] foo = GetFoo<int?>(3);
```

Comment: Very true @Habib - I guess it is just a special value type that plays nicely with null, where the other value types do not.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` just have bool flag `HasValue` which is set to true in case of assignment to `null`. It is a `struct` with two properties, one to hold the `Value` and the other to indicate whether it is assigned `null` or a normal value.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` can't be of type `int`.But it can be of type `int?`. Do `int?[]` and it will have nulls. As it fills array with `default(T)` which in case of T `int?` will be `NULL`.

Comment: @canon yeah typo  -fills-